# I have an old bitcoin core/qt wallet - how do I extract the forks?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoin-cash, bitcoin-gold

I can access the wallet, and move my bitcoin to other addresses, but it doesn't show me the fork coins. (Bitcoin-Cash, Bitcoin Gold, and perhaps more?) Can I access them through some other wallet?

What would I need to extract all forks from my wallet to a modern one (Say, a Trezor)?

I created a legacy bitcoin wallet in my trezor, and moved my bits to it, but the bitcoin cash and gold never appears in my wallet.

Comment: here you can find a bunch of info about claiming fork coins: https://99bitcoins.com/bitcoin-forks. your question is off topic here.